# Storing echoed strings in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, echo

How to grab the string that a function echoes to a variable?

I've go a function similar to this:

```
    function echoer() {
        echo 'foo';
    }
```

I cannot change it's source. What I would like to do is to store 'foo' in a variable instead of letting it go to the standard output. How is it done in PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ob_start()` will start an output buffer which will suppress all content. Then, after you have done all the output, call `ob_get_contents()` and assign it to a variable. Finally call `ob_end_clean()` to start echoing normally again.

```
ob_start()

echo "This content won't be echoed immediatley";

$contents = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $contents;
```

as Milen mentioned, check out [Output Control functions.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

This method is very useful, especially for working with Wordpress, which is set to output most things, like comments, and doesn't provide a return function.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).