# Save an include's output to a string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing echoed strings in a variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195588/storing-echoed-strings-in-a-variable-in-php)

Suppose I have

```
<?php include "print-stuff.php"; ?>
```

*print-stuff.php* contains PHP/HTML template, which means that when it is included, HTML gets printed. Is there any way to capture that HTML as a string, so that I may save it to use elsewhere?

Moving the include statement elsewhere is not an option, because *print-stuff.php* also performs logic (creates/modifies variables) that the surrounding code depends on. I simply want to move the file's output, while leaving its logic as is.

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195588/storing-echoed-strings-in-a-variable-in-php/

Comment: I'm not sure if the questions are duplicate, but the answers to both questions are the same. If I were to decide this is duplicate, my reputation isn't high enough to close the question :(

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
$fileStr = file_get_contents('/path/not/url/to/script.php');
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: -1 Isn't this answer really wrong? Wouldn't it just load the source code? At least to get the output, not the source, it should be `/url/not/path/to/script.php`. But even then, the question indicates that there are some preconditions this includes requires, which would be not handled with the `url` solution.

Answer (score 35):

You can [Output Buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) it to make sure the HTML isn't shown and is instead put into a variable. (PHP will still run, but HTML output will be contained in the variable)

```
ob_start();
include "print-stuff.php";
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

....

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I came on here and went ah-ha, I know the answer to this!!! Then I looked down and saw other people got to it before I did.

But, for the heck of it, I do like this:

```
ob_start();
include 'something.php';
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: This answer made me look up https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers -- Seems like p4bl0's within minutes answer is fine, but this really confuses me. Enough to comment on it 8 years later :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at output buffering.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you print in a buffer instead of stdout.

```
ob_start();
include 'print-stuff.php';
$printedHTML = ob_get_clean();
```