# PHP Function echo included file

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.0

I'm currently developing a wordpress plugin. I created a shortcode which displays the content of another html/php file this looks like this:

```
function df_display_form()
{
    // Fetching some data with $wpdb

    // Display the data
    include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'markup/show-dynamic-form.php';
}
```

My problem is that the shortcode will be showed at the top of the page. So I googled this issus and found a [solution](https://freshwebdev.com/solved-wordpress-shortcode-always-appear-on-the-top-of-content.html). As it is writte there the problem is that `return` should be used instead of `echo`.

So my question is how can I return the renderd content from the included file? (not echo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing echoed strings in a variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195588/storing-echoed-strings-in-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an output buffer. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

```
function df_display_form()
{
    ob_start(); 
    // Fetching some data with $wpdb

    // Display the data
    include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'markup/show-dynamic-form.php';
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use php fuction to display the form using shortcode.

I think you have currently this type of code in show-dynamic-form.php file.

```
<?php

// Some codes

?>

<form>

Form elements

</form>
```

It will just echo your code to the top of your post or page. Correct way is:

```
<?php

    // Some codes

    $variable = '<form>';
    $variable .= 'form elements';
    $variable .= '</form>';

    return $variable;

?>
```

Try to use this way in your dynamic-form.php file and it should work.